# Adding Dataset in RDLC report Takes hours on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, report, reporting, rdlc

After shifting my project from visual studio 2012 to 2013 cannot able to add data set. It takes nearly two or more hour.In that time visual studio stops working. So I cannot able to add or modify anything in my solution. I have both Visual Studio 2012,2013.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using the wrong framework. Right click your project and make sure that the `Target framework` is set correctly.

If the project was build with an older version than the .NET Framework 4 or 4.5 this may cause issues when trying to target the newer frameworks.

This MSDN guide on [How to: Configure an App to Support .NET Framework 4 or 4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935(v=vs.110).aspx) might be able to help you.